# Cannot access sender of message in anylogic

Tags: message, anylogic

I am trying to access the sender of a message ( sender is a person agent) to evaluate the connection between the sender and the receiver as a condition for a transition. 
In anylogic help it say you can use msg to access the message content which has worked and the sender using sender.

I have tried using `sender = msgSender`

where msgSender is a variable. 
However I get the error message `sender cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: Show the minimal full code required to replicate the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send your message to a `Link to agent` object and not to a statechart directly.

You can access the sender if your message arrives via a `Link to agent`  block such as the default one called `connections`, see below:
[image]

In it, you can decide to forward the message to a statechart (if your sender is the right one).

Comment: My links are unidirectional as model mother and child connections. the code I use to send is `children.sendToAllConnected(destination); `This means I can't access the communications as are received in standard connection links

Answer (score 0):

An Agent's `connections` element (default **Link to agents**) receives *all* messages sent to that agent (which are also then passed on by default to any statecharts, but you can control that in the `connections` properties). The exception is if the message comes from a bidirectional connection (in which case the message will only be accessible in *that* **Link to agents** in the 'far end' agent).

If you have a unidirectional set of connections from mother to child (let's say from Mother type agent to Child type agent, with the **Link to agents** in Mother called `children`) then you can access the message and sender (using keywords as you mentioned from the help) in the default `connections` element of your Child agent.

You also need to ensure that you are sending the message to all connected *via the appropriate Link to Agents*. So you need something like:

(a) In Mother agent:
`children.sendToAllConnected("Hello");`

(b) In Child agent `connections` *On message received* action:
`traceln("Got message " + msg + " from sender " + sender);`

(In your case obviously you would have logic doing something dependent on the sender.)

P.S. You said you were trying to do `sender = msgSender`. That doesn't quite make sense: were you attempting to *set* the message sender to something? You can't do that: `sender` is only available in the receiving agent's **Link to agents** action and always references the actual sender agent. (You can't 'fake' the sender for example, and don't ever have to set it.)